# Dynamic variables angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I would like to be able to display some overlay when you focus on an `img` element. The problem is that the elements are populated from the attributes of an angularjs `ng-repeat` I would like only a specific img to enable a specific text.

The below example [does not work](http://jsfiddle.net/Zrj9R/3/), the `ng-class` variable resolves correctly though.

```
<div class="myClass" ng-repeat="i in items">
 <span class="class-img-wrapper">
  <img ng-src="{{i.img}}"  class="class-img-view" ng-init="{{i.name}}_focused = false" ng-focus="{{i.name}}_focused = true" ng-blur="{{i.name}}_focused = false"/>
  <span ng-class="{classOverlayShow: {{i.name}}_focused}" class="class-img-overlay">
    {{i.name}}
  </span>
 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: `doesn't work` really isn't very informative. We can't see data, or controller, or know what is or isn't happening....show more code and create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: `doesn't work` now has a fiddle :)

Comment: explain what you expect the `ng-class` to do based on name? Not making sense without explanation. No idea what `_focused` is about. Right side of `ng-class` needs to resolve to true/false

Comment: also need to improve css selector specificity  http://jsfiddle.net/Zrj9R/4/

Comment: if you look at the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Zrj9R/3/ you can see that the ng-class value is resolved to a variable named bob_focused or frank_focused but the ng-init, ng-focus and ng-blur do not

Comment: img isn't a focusable element, can't edit it...http://jsfiddle.net/nYrXq/  ....whole thing can be done using `:hover` css. Neither is span  http://jsfiddle.net/nYrXq/1/

Answer (score 1):

That does not look like valid syntax to me:

```html
<span ng-class="{classOverlayShow: {{i.name}}_focused}" class="class-img-overlay">
```

It should read something along the lines of:

```html
 <span ng-class="{classOverlayShow: i.name + '_focused' }" class="class-img-overlay">
```

---

Why not add the `focussed` field to your models in `items`?

Instead of `ng-init="{{i.name}}_focused = false"` and then using `ng-focus="{{i.name}}_focused = true" ng-blur="{{i.name}}_focused = false"` to create dynamic variables on the fly (which I suspect doesn't work because it isn't valid angular syntax), do this instead:

**Controller**

```js
$scope.items.forEach(function (i) {
    i.focussed = false;
});

$scope.setOverlay = function (item) {
    item.focussed = true;
};

$scope.removeOverlay = function (item) {
    item.focussed = false;
};
```

**Template**

```
<div class="myClass" ng-repeat="i in items">
 <span class="class-img-wrapper">
  <img ng-src="{{i.img}}"  class="class-img-view" ng-focus="setOverlay(i)" ng-blur="removeOverlay(i)"/>
  <span ng-class="{classOverlayShow: i.focussed }" class="class-img-overlay">
    {{i.name}}
  </span>
 </span>
</div>
```

However, [angular documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angFocus) suggests that the `ngFocus` directive works only for `input`, `textarea`, `select`, `window` and `a` tags. So for *focus* events, you may have to create your own directive and bind to `onfocus` events yourself, or switch to simpler and more ubiquitous `ng-click`.

Comment: thanks i updated that part, although it is not valid it does work!

Comment: I have suggested a more angular-esque solution.

Comment: @AlexEdwards Did you notice the update to the answer?

Comment: Yes but I ran out of time to look at it, sometime this weekend hopefully, thank you